# Best way to test a web app on a specific phone without that phone

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, testing, webview

I need to test a web app on the S7 edge, however I don't have one. The web app works with other phones but for the S7 edge, the conversion rate is actually 0. What is the best way to test the way the phone is interacting with the web app, without owning the actual hardware.

I have android studio and was going to try using webview, but I think you need the device for that. I was thinking about using appium but I'm not sure if it would give me a diagnostics of what scripts were/weren't running.

Any suggestions?

Comment: why not to use device farm for testing? For instance Amazon has S7 http://awsdevicefarm.info/

Answer (score 0):

You can run an emulator in Android Studio. Since the S7 Edge is not available for download directly through Android Studio, you would have install your own hardware profile for S7 Edge (an emulator).

Here's a good link to download it: https://medium.com/@ssaurel/install-samsung-galaxy-s7-and-s7-edge-skins-in-your-android-emulator-846bbcd84d24

To install this emulator, in Android Studio click 'Run' and go to 'Create a new Virtual Device'. There will then be an option to import a hardware profile and select the file you just downloaded.

Hope this helps! If you have any trouble with this, let me know!

Comment: I believe this will be vanilla Android with an S7 Edge skin.  It will not have TouchWiz or any other Samsung customizations.  That may or may not be fine for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Device Farm is another option.  You can run tests on real devices.  However as far as I know you have to code the test in Espresso or some other framework; you cannot just start up a phone and interact with it.  I don't know if they have the S7 Edge - they don't have all phone models available.